# How to get the approximate background color of an image?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, colors

Is there a way to get the approximate background color from an image in Flutter? I am getting my image from a URL. I don't need an exact background color: just an approximation - for instance, getting the color of the pixel in the top left corner (0, 0) would be just fine.

There seems to be no easy way to do this - I have tried many imaging packages, but they only provide "primary color" and not background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question, but for people still needing this, see the `ImagePixels` widget from the https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels package (I am the author of this package):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ImagePixels(
              imageProvider: image,
              builder: (context, img) {
                  Color topLeftColor = img.pixelColorAt(0, 0);
                  Text("Pixel color at top-left: $topLeftColor.");
              );}}
```

Note you could also get a dozen pixels all around the image (or at the corners of the image), and then average them. This would have a better chance of getting a good representative color.

Also note, if all you want to do with this color is to extend it to a larger area, there is a constructor that does that for you: `ImagePixels.container`.

Comment: @martijn-pieters This answer is actually tailored to the question. The question is similar but it's not identical to others, and the answer is also similar but not identical.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package?

If you just want the top left corner pixel, I believe you can read the image's pixels and get it.

Comment: There seems to be no way to get an image from the internet using that package, but it could work if I knew how to get images from the internet and load them into the image package.

Comment: You need to get the image from the internet yourself, then load the image's bytes to the functions provided by the image package. I think the "decode" functions would be the ones to supply the bytes. See the package's examples.